# vim regex: deleting character based on position

Tags: regex, vim

This is similar to question [VIM: insert or delete data based on position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133712/vim-insert-or-delete-data-based-on-position)

I am trying to replace (not just insert) the desired text at position 7 in every line in a file.  Based on the regex provided in the solution in the above question, I tried:

```
a. %s/\%=7c/text/  (failed error message - illegal character)
b. %s/\%7c/text/g   (says correct amount of lines / changes were made BUT blank space is still there after "text")
c. %s/\%7c/text/ (same as b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/%7c` will insert at character 7

you'll want your match to be the following, so that it includes the next character:

```
%s/\%7c./text/
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to Bob Vale's correct answer, the `\%c` atom is a *zero-width* match. That is, it only limits the match (here: to the character position), but it **does not consume any characters**. You need to do that by putting a corresponding atom behind it (here: `.` will match any character). The better-known `\<` atom behaves the same.

#### Note for non-ASCII encodings

There's a caveat: the `\%c` matches byte numbers of the underlying representation, so it won't work as expected when there are non-ASCII characters. It's likely that you're actually interested in the *screen column* (this also matters when there's a `<Tab>` character in front of the match: it counts as one byte, but has a screen column width of between 1 and 8). Vim calls this *virtual column* and has the `\%v` atom for it.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to use [visual block mode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/selecting-columns-with-visual-block-mode/) for that kind of things (there is little chance I'll remember that zero-width expression syntax).