# How to Insert character based on position VIM

Tags: vim

So far what I know.
the **'^'** character is a special search character denoted for the start of line.
and **g** denoted to global change.
Based on [How to add text at the end of each line in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303032/how-to-add-text-at-the-end-of-each-line-in-vim) and [How to insert text at beginning of a multi-line selection in vi/Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253380/how-to-insert-text-at-beginning-of-a-multi-line-selection-in-vi-vim)

```
: - enter command mode
% - for every line
s/ - substitute
$ - the end of the line
/ - and change it to
, - a comma
```

---

Below there is: **3 fields: integer, string/alphabetic, integer.**
I have been trying to solve the following problems.

- insert a comma `,` after first integer value field.
- insert single quote `''`  for the second alphabetic string,
- insert an comma to separate string value field to the last integer
  value field.

```
    (1     a        80
    (1     b        50
    (2     a        90
    (2     b        120
    (3     a        200
    (3     b        140
    (4     a        110
    (4     b        430
```

Comment: Your "problems" are stated ambiguously. Add an "after" sample that shows exactly what you want to obtain and show us what you tried. Also, Vim comes with a very thorough yet very easy to follow built-in tutorial, `:help user-manual`. Follow it instead of convincing yourself that you are learning Vim via stack exchange answers, you are not.

Comment: Please do not include pictures of text - rather include the text as text, so people can copy it and try out answers/methods.

Comment: @mattb. I attached text.

Comment: @Mark - thanks, can you also add text of what it should look like afterwards? And also remove the image. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to use Ex, then

```
:%s/\((\d\+\)\s\+\(\w\+\)\s\+\(\d\+\)/\1, '\2', \3
```

and press enter. The `\(` `\)` blocks are the vim regex equivalent of regex groups. To learn more about vim regex, which is a lot different from normal regex: http://www.vimregex.com/

Comment: Thanks. But already wrap it in group as (). Then I am not sure I understand  \s\+\

Answer (score 0):

Because your data is aligned, visual mode would make this easy. Assuming you don't want to touch the whitespace, which could be tabs or spaces:

```
CTRL-v           # enter visual mode with cursor on first int in first line
j or down arrow  # to the last line/last int
shift-i , ESCAPE # to insert comma and apply to visual range
```

The single quote problem is almost the same, except hit shift-a to append the trailing single quote. For adding a comma to the end, select on any column to end and hit:

```
$A,
```

which will append to the end of the line. I am also assuming here there is no trailing whitespace else it will be at the end of that.

Comment: of course, if they are spaces and you don't care, select the columns after or before and hit  r(comma,quote) to simply replace the space with appropriate punctuation.